# Axios React Doesn't append information Get Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hash, axios

I've been looking for a while on Stack but I cannot work out a solution.

I have one method that invoked should do a GET request with Axios.

At the beginning of the method I created a new hash , so I want to store all information there and then just return that hash.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
class Json extends Component{
  getInformation(){
    let inf = {};
     axios
      .get("http://codepen.io/jobs.json")
      .then(result=> {
        inf.description = result.data.jobs[0].description;

      })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.log("STH WRONG");
      });

      console.log(inf);
    return(inf);
  }
```

So what's my problem???? If I check what is inside the inf variable, it's empty. However, if I inspect with Chrome, on console I see it empty but when i check with detail the key and value are there. At the moment that i am trying to retrieve the information with `inf.description` is undefined.

Any idea?? Feel free to try this example, just invoke  this method to check it.

**EDIT**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
class Json extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={title: ""};

  }
  getInformation(){
    let inf = {};

    // .get("/data/CA_data.json")
     axios
      .get("http://codepen.io/jobs.json")
      .then(result=> {
        inf.description = result.data.jobs[0].description;

      })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.log("STH WRONG");
      });

      console.log(inf);
    return(inf);
  }

  render(){
    let inf = this.getInformation();

    return(
      <h1>

      </h1>
    );
  }
}


export default Json;
```

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: I'll check it well when i'll be on the laptop! It looks really interesting and useful

Comment: @azium Man really thanks for this link. I had some issues there and thanks to this i fixed!

Answer (score 1):

When you make a `get` request with `axios`, you are invoking something that creates a Promise object which represents the status of the async request made.  This could be a failed response, a resolved (successful) response, or ***pending***.

The reason you are having issues obtaining the correct state are then you have logged the data immediately after you have invoked your `get` call and at this point, `inf.description` is not what you expected it to be but is most likely the Promise object with status 'pending'.

Here is a proposed solution for you:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
class Json extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { inf: {} }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.getInformation();  // make the axios call in this lifecycle method
  }
  getInformation(){
    return axios
      .get("http://codepen.io/jobs.json")
      .then(result=> {
        this.setState({ inf.description: result.data.jobs[0].description });
        // this.state.inf.description is available here because
        // then() gets called once the promise has been resolved

        // the call to this.setState causes a re-render of this component
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.log("STH WRONG");
      });
  }
  render(){
    // this header will initially show the initial value of description
    // once the PROMISE from the getInformation call within 
    // componentDidMount resolves and calls this.setState, 
    // this component will re-render with the updated state value(s)

    <div>{ this.state.inf.description }</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: console.log is just to test. I want to store the information inside inf hash. What i want to return is the hash inf

Comment: I see, what you can do is save it on state, I've amended my answer accordingly

Comment: i've tried as well. And i don't know why but i'm entering on a loop of undefined!!!! Really weird

Comment: I'm not on the computer but the rest is just the render and a variable invoking this method...

Comment: :) knowing the specifics would allow me to provide a more specific and useful answer, what I've provided so far should solve your issue of not being able to assign the response to a components state.

Comment: I edit the problem. So here it is all my code for this test

Comment: @Ruffeng You're still assuming the request is synchronous, which it isn't. You return from `getInformation` before the request has completed.

Comment: @DaveNewton  i can understand you but i am not sure how to fix it. Could you purpose me a solution?

Comment: @DaveNewton you could put your axios call within the componentDidMount lifecycle call, I'll update my answer to represent this

Comment: @Pineda  i'll try it! Really thank you for your help

Comment: @Pineda. It works! Really thanks for your help. I wasn't doing async, so for this reason was all time in blank. Now I can understand well. Really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Excellent! I'd very much appreciate marking as accepted if you feel my answer is deserving of it. Either way: Glad I could help :).